# Need help to add time series to my plot of missing values ggplot_na_distribution

Tags: r

i'm working with the function ggplot_na_distribution() to plot the missing values in my data set and i want to show the time series in the x axis. Does anyone know how to do it?
I've tried with the date column and the transformed one with POSIXct.

ggplot_na_distribution(data$precipitation_REF)